# Salesforce Upsert Differing Fields

Tags: upsert

So,

I have a situation, and I am trying to decide between an upsert, and an update + insert.  I am thinking it will be the latter.  Is it possible to ONLY upsert values that are null within Salesforce? If a Firstname, Lastname are populated within SF, is it possible to leave those bem and only update other fields?  But create them on the insert portion of the upsert?